# T-SQL Retrieve rows with default values on records that don't meet search criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help setting default values for records that don't meet my search criteria in the WHERE clause.  The WHERE clause can be built dynamically each run so sometimes buyers won't be in the result set but I want a record of that to show 0 for their counts and values.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT h.PONum) AS unconfirmedCount,
   ISNULL(SUM(d.DocExtCost), 0) AS unconfirmedValue,
    CASE v.Buyer_c
        WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'
        ELSE v.Buyer_c
     END AS buyerID    

FROM [Dbo].POHeader AS h

INNER JOIN [Dbo].PODetail AS d
        ON (h.Company = d.Company AND 
            h.PONum = d.PONum)

INNER JOIN [Dbo].Vendor AS v
        ON (h.Company = v.Company AND 
            h.VendorNum = v.VendorNum) 

WHERE h.FirstPublishedToPortal_c < DATEADD(HOUR, 24, GETDATE())
     AND v.Buyer_c IN ('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5')
     AND h.ReadyForSupplierPortal_c = 1
     AND ( h.Confirmed = 0 OR h.Confirmed IS NULL )

 GROUP BY CASE v.Buyer_c
             WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'
             ELSE v.Buyer_c
          END             

 UNION SELECT 0, 0, 'Person1'
 UNION SELECT 0, 0, 'Person2'
 UNION SELECT 0, 0, 'Person3'
 UNION SELECT 0, 0, 'Person4'
```

This is the current result:

[image]

This is my desired result set:
[image]

I want the person with no results to still have a record in my result set. I don't understand how to use distinct for just one column. DISTINCT only works on entire rows, but of course the rows are different because of the UNION.

Comment: I am not believing that group by is valid.  I tested a simple case and it does not throw a syntax error but it will not execute.  How does a variable group by make sense?

Comment: The group by and case are actually working. The reason is that Person 4 & Person 5 are really the same person inputting orders under different buyerIDs (for some business purpose). But mgmt wants this summary report to include all their efforts in one result instead of two separate rows hence the need to group their results together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the answer, I assume your result (in that big SELECT) can be in a table (for example, you can use CTE to enclose your SELECT query). With that in mind, here is the result (treat #s as your big SELECT result)

```
create table #s ([Count] int, [Value] int, [BuyerID] varchar(10))

insert into #s values (1, 250, 'Person1'), (1, 285, 'Person2'), (1, 1560, 'Person3')


select [UnconfirmedCount]=(isnull(s.[count],0)+ t.[count]) 
, [UnconfirmedValue]=isnull(s.[value],0)+t.[value],
, buyerID = case when s.BuyerID is not null then s.BuyerID else t.BuyerID end 
from #s s
right join (values (0, 0, 'Person1'), (0, 0, 'Person2'), (0, 0, 'Person3'), (0, 0, 'Person4')) T([Count], [Value], [BuyerID] ) 
on s.BuyerID = t.BuyerID
```

[image]

If you want to re-write your query, it should be like the following (sorry, I did not build table to test it, but you can try yourself)

```
; with s ([Count], [Value], buyerID) as
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT h.PONum) AS unconfirmedCount,
   ISNULL(SUM(d.DocExtCost), 0) AS unconfirmedValue,
    CASE v.Buyer_c
        WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'
        ELSE v.Buyer_c
     END AS buyerID    

FROM [Dbo].POHeader AS h

INNER JOIN [Dbo].PODetail AS d
        ON (h.Company = d.Company AND 
            h.PONum = d.PONum)

INNER JOIN [Dbo].Vendor AS v
        ON (h.Company = v.Company AND 
            h.VendorNum = v.VendorNum) 

WHERE h.FirstPublishedToPortal_c < DATEADD(HOUR, 24, GETDATE())
     AND v.Buyer_c IN ('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5')
     AND h.ReadyForSupplierPortal_c = 1
     AND ( h.Confirmed = 0 OR h.Confirmed IS NULL )

 GROUP BY CASE v.Buyer_c
             WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'
             ELSE v.Buyer_c
          END             
)
select [UnconfirmedCount]=(isnull(s.[count],0)+ t.[count]), [UnconfirmedValue]=isnull(s.[value],0)+t.[value]
, buyerID = case when s.BuyerID is not null then s.BuyerID else t.BuyerID end 
from  s
right join (values (0, 0, 'Person1'), (0, 0, 'Person2'), (0, 0, 'Person3'), (0, 0, 'Person4')) T([Count], [Value], [BuyerID] ) 
on s.BuyerID = t.BuyerID
```

Comment: This worked great but I don't understand at all how it worked. What is this: `;with s ([Count], [Value], buyerID) as`  doing?

Comment: @S.Mason, that is called Common Table Expression (abbr as CTE), for details, you can see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Couple ways you could skin this cat. First, you could just include all the users in the original aggregation. Put the stuff in your `where` clause into a `case` statement to sum instead. e.g.

```
...sum(case when <your where clause stuff evaulates true> then null else d.DocExtCost end)...
```

Then you still get all the buyers, but their values are nulled out (and thus evaulated to 0, with your `isnull()`.

Alternatively, you could get a list of all your buyers up front, either as a temp table, or just inline using a derive table. You can then left join that set of users to the aggregation you have right now (excluding the unioned rows of course) and do `isnull(aggregate.SumDocExtCost, 0)`

Comment: I was going to suggest the LEFT JOIN approach

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` without `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `case` in the `group by`. I don't believe that works. If you need to map 'Person5' to 'Person4' then do that with a table and a join

Why PODetail AS d?  You are not using it.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT h.PONum) AS unconfirmedCount,
       SUM(ISNULL(d.DocExtCost, 0)) AS unconfirmedValue,
       v.Buyer_c 
  from [Dbo].Vendor AS v            
  left join [Dbo].POHeader AS h
    ON h.Company   = v.Company 
   AND h.VendorNum = v.VendorNum
   and h.FirstPublishedToPortal_c < DATEADD(HOUR, 24, GETDATE())
   AND h.ReadyForSupplierPortal_c = 1
   AND isnull(h.Confirmed, 0) = 0    
  left JOIN [Dbo].PODetail AS d
    ON d.Company = h.Company 
   and d.PONum   = h.PONum    
 WHERE v.Buyer_c IN ('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5')         
 GROUP BY v.Buyer_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  CTE (Common Table Expressions):

```
  ;With buyers AS (BuyerId)
  ( 
     -- Select Distinct BuyerID
  ),

  unconfirmedCounts AS (UnconfirmedCount, UnconfirmedValue, BuyerId)
  ( 
      -- Select Counts & Value for each Buyer where available
  )

  Select ISNULL(u.UnconfirmedCount,0) AS UnconfirmedCount,
         ISNULL(u.UnconfirmedValue,0) AS UnconfirmedValue,
         b.BuyerId as BuyerId
 FROM buyers b
 LEFT JOIN unconfirmedCounts u on b.BuyerId = u.BuyerId;
```